# Count a pattern of string in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a column named source_id
That has records like

```
12334xxx45566
33445xxx5566, 12344xxx4456
22487xxx5234, 98776xxx6789, 34455xxx7828
```

Output I am expecting, is the counts of 'xxx' in each row

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_matches()` which returns each match as a row:

```
select source_id, (select count(*) from regexp_matches(source_id, 'xxx', 'g')) as counts
from the_table;
```

Comment: that works!!  thank you soo much. However, is it possible to add the source_id and counts. both these columns

Comment: select "Source_Id", (select count(*) from regexp_matches("Source_id", 'xxx', 'g')) as counts
from table_name

Comment: Well, just add `source_id` to the SELECT list.

Comment: Works now perfectly :)

Comment: @arshiya you should accept the answer if it resolves your problem

Comment: a_horse: I believe you are [being pinged here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399617/using-pivot-in-postgresql) `:=)`.